# Custom property: gotta be something obvious I'm doing wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have been adding partial classes of my different entities to add various useful methods without issue.

Attempting to add properties appears to be straightforward based on examples that I've seen, but mine are failing miserably.

**Updated** example:

```
        public List<Friend> FriendsInGoodStanding
    {
        get
        {
            using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
            {
                var a = context.Friends.Include("aspnet_User1").Where(f => f.UserID == this.UserId && f.Blocked == false).ToList();
                var b = context.Friends.Include("aspnet_User").Where(f => f.FriendUserID == this.UserId && f.Blocked == false).ToList();
                a.AddRange(b);
                return a.Distinct().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am receiving the following error any time I attempt to make use of this property:

> The ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.

```
Line 4936:            get
Line 4937:            {
Line 4938:                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<aspnet_User>("GarbageModel.FK_Friends_aspnet_Users", "aspnet_User").Value;
Line 4939:            }
```

This must be something obvious that I've overlooked.

Comment: I'm getting the same exception, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, because you have not tried my solution yet, you need to call Include() method twice on the same query with both "aspnet_User" and "aspnet_User1" not each of them on two different query and then trying to merging them.

Comment: Sorry, that's because the other navigation property refers to the user whose property it is in the first place.  For each friendship I create two records in the "Friends" table, with the userIDs swapped: (1,2) (2,1)

Comment: That's fine, what's important is that you have 2 nav property on the Friend class and you need to Include them "both" on "any" query. Let me update my solution, it then might make more sense.

Comment: I updated my answer by yet another way to get over with this exception. Please check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of this error is because your program is trying to "Lazy Load" one of the navigation properties on your Friend entity object and this happens when you already read the *FriendsInGoodStanding* property and the objectcontext has been disposed, because of the using statement.

Now, I can see that you are eager loading "aspnet_User1" and also you are calling ToList() at the end of your query so it must be another navigation property on the *Friend* object. If you show the client code that uses the *FriendsInGoodStanding* property then I can exactly tell which one is that but for now my hunch is that you have a property named aspnet_User on Friend object which also needs to be eager load like this:

```
public partial class aspnet_User{

    public List FriendsInGoodStanding {
        get {
            using (var context = new GarbageEntities()) {

                var a = context.Friends
                     .Include("aspnet_User1")
                     .Include("aspnet_User")
                     .Where(f => f.UserID == this.UserId && f.Blocked == false).ToList();

                var b = context.Friends
                     .Include("aspnet_User")
                     .Include("aspnet_User1")
                     .Where(f => f.FriendUserID == this.UserId && f.Blocked == false).ToList();
                a.AddRange(b);
                return a.Distinct().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Another Solution:**

would be to **disable lazy loading** for your object context to get over with this exception. You can do so by right clicking on your model and then selecting properties and then find "Lazy Loading Enabled" option which is true by default, just set it to false. Or programmatically you can code:

```
var context = new GarbageEntities();
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Once it is disabled, you can still explicitly load related data on demand if needed, or
even load the data along with the initial query.
Just watch out for NullReferenceException!

Comment: I will double check on this as soon as I put out the smoldering lasagna in my oven.  Thanks.

Comment: If you could not find the missed nav property, just post your client code and we'll go from there.

Comment: I appreciate all your help.  This is no longer generating an exception, but I have no idea why I have to query for both navigation properties when I have no need of them.  Am I just using the wrong query altogether?  Is there any easier way?  Thanks.

Comment: Disabling lazy loading is generally a good idea for web applications?

Comment: No problem. Well, if you don't need them both then you should refactor your client code and remove the unnecessary calls to aspnet_User1 and aspnet_User nav properties since at some point you are calling them both and because they are not loaded, EF tries to lazy load them and it fails (they might even being called from your MVC View pages so you need to inspect all layers of your application) the easier (not the better) way would be my 2nd solution by disabling Lazy Loading on your context. It will probably cause NullReferenceException though.

Comment: I'm guessing there must be some place in my code that is looking for that navigation property that I don't know about...

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice "in general" for WCF and Web applications to always disable Lazy Loading. Like I said, Once it is disabled, you can still explicitly load related data on demand if needed, or eager load them with the initial query. In your case I would say you should first refactor your code and then disable lazy loading.